# Eclipse Launch error

Tags: java, eclipse, error-handling

Started getting this error after an update and have tried some common solutions such as adding `-vm` to `ini.` and deleting .metadata folder but it did not work.

This is the error I am getting, thank you for your help.

```
!SESSION 2017-10-22 21:21:31.153 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.1.M20171009-0410
java.version=1.8.0_144
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=es_EC
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-10-22 21:21:35.333
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4533)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4448)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4419)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1263)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.checkDevice(Display.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.addListener(Display.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.<init>(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.<init>(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
```